# multiple forms, possibly one css file

Tags: css

my name is Frank, I have two html files, each having a form with it's own purpose, do I need two css files for them, having each form it's own css or can I use one css file using some kind of grouping, the last would be preferable but I do not know how, I would realy appreciate your help, Thank You, Frank.
ps. : in need case I can send my examples.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp and look for external style sheet

Answer (score 0):

Multiple HTML pages can use the same CSS by linking to an external file. In the `<head>` of each HTML file place:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/style.css" >`

Inside your CSS file (just CSS no markup) you can target both form elements by using HTML tags as the selector.

```
form {
  // shared form styles
}

input {
  // shared input styling
}
```

Comment: i think I can not put input{} inside form{} plus having more then one form with different purpose, I am facing difficulties separating form styling css, otherwise the browser wiil be confused.

Comment: i think using the same css file for more than one html file content has to be separated safely addressing the html files correctly.